# Why intent.getParcelableExtra don't return nullable type in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an example of extracting data from intent

```
val screen = intent.getParcelableExtra<Screen>("screen")
```

The result I received is a not nullable variable, but it can be null because I don't know if that parcelable has been added to extras. Why kotlin doesn't return a nullable type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin just calls `getParcelableExtra()` as it is defined in in the android SDK in java. This method is not annotated with `@Nullable` so kotlin doesn't know it might return null.

Also see [nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations):

> **Nullability annotations**
>   Java types which have nullability annotations
>   are represented not as platform types, but as actual nullable or
>   non-null Kotlin types. The compiler supports several flavors of
>   nullability annotations, including:
>
> - JetBrains (@Nullable and @NotNull from the org.jetbrains.annotations
>     package)
> - Android (com.android.annotations and android.support.annotations)

Answer (score 3):

In the code

> ```
> val screen = intent.getParcelableExtra<Screen>("screen")
> ```

the inferred type of `screen` will be `Screen!`. The exclamation mark indicates that this is a *platform type*, which means that it may or may not be nullable, but the compiler won't enforce null-checking behavior.

Read more: [Null Safety and Platform Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)

If you actively want Kotlin to enforce null safety, though, you can specify the type explicitly:

```
val screen: Screen? = intent.getParcelableExtra<Screen>("screen")
```

By specifying the type explicitly, Kotlin will give you all the compile-time null safety you're used to.